# How can I replace part of a label in a dataframe with pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is loaded from a .csv, and I would like to remove some text in the labels.

Right now, my dataframe save the labels as ***output.text.user.12***, ***output.text.user.1224***,...
I would like to remove from that labels the part ***"output.text.user."***

```
        output.text.user.12  ...  output.text.user.23424
index                        ...                                 
332                 0.06924  ...                     0.0
```

Does anyone know how could I do it?
I've seen how to replace the current name from a dictionary, but it's a too long dataframe to do it.

Comment: by labels you mean columns?

Comment: would you like to remove numbers from the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.rename` is what you want. Assuming your dataframe is `df`

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('output.text.user.', ''))
```

Comment: Do you also know how could I delete columns which contains some specific text?? As an example, if it a column contains 'output.text.profile', delete it.

Comment: @Sergio: Untested but `df.drop(columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'output.text.profile' in str(col)], inplace=True)` should do it. Control with [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop)

Comment: Do you know how to do the same but with the keys of a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd

# your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over columns, split by dot (.) and select last item in resulting list
new_columns = []
for column in df.columns:
    new_columns.append(column.split('.')[-1])

# assign new column names to your dataframe by overwriting the old ones
df.columns = new_columns
```